# Will a new AJAX request from a separate function like this cancel an old one out?

Tags: ajax

If I have two separate functions, each with similar AJAX data like this ...

1.

```
$.ajax(
{
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{test:test},       
        url:"myScript.php?="+jQuery.now(),
        success:function(data)
        {// alert(data.toSource());
```

2.

```
$.ajax(
{
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{test2:test2},     
        url:"mySecondScript.php?="+jQuery.now(),
        success:function(data)
        {// alert(data.toSource());
```

Is AJAX designed so that if the AJAX calls are running simultaneously, they both know which function to return to?

I have a polling function, and I'm wondering if it's ok to have it running while AJAX calls invoked by the user are also running.

Currently, if the user invokes something that requires an AJAX call (call it Process1), and during that a poll in the background occurs (Process2 - totally independent of Process1), Process1 doesn't seem to complete.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898238/does-the-callback-passed-to-jquerys-get-execute-in-a-separate-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, will be done all ajax requests and functions!